# Calculate average on a row then write the result in another sheet cell if some data match

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have an excel file with 2 sheets.
In the first sheet i have 100 column x 23 rows. First column contain names and other 99 columns contain numbers.
In the second sheet, i have first column with names.
I want to add in the second sheet the average of the 99 column from first sheet if the names matches. 
This is what i have tried until now:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(".xlsx")
ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')
ws2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet2')

for counter1 in range(39,62):   #counter to parse second sheet
    for counter2 in range(36, 62):#counter to parse first sheet
        if ws1.cell(row=counter1, column=1).value == ws2.cell(row=counter2, column=1).value:   # check if column1 from first sheet matches column 1 from second sheet
            ws1.cell(row=counter1,column=19).value = ...
```

i dont know how to calculate the average of the 99 columns to add it here.
I have tried mean(ws2.cell(row=counter2, column=2).value),
but i got this error:
TypeError:cant convert type "unicode" to numerator/denoiminator

Any help is welcomed

Comment: Why a nested loop? Why are you not using more of the openpyxl API? Why don't you use Python's builtin `sum()` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(".xlsx")
ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')
ws2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet2')

for counter1 in range(39,62):   #counter to parse second sheet
    for counter2 in range(36, 62):#counter to parse first sheet
        if ws1.cell(row=counter1, column=1).value == ws2.cell(row=counter2, column=1).value:   # check if column1 from first sheet matches column 1 from second sheet
            summ = 0.0
            for col in range(2,101):
                summ += float(ws1.cell(row = counter2, column = col).value)
            average = summ/99
            ws1.cell(row=counter1,column=19).value = average
```

So I would calculate the means myself, by summing up the column values and dividing the sum by the number of columns.

Are you sure, though, that counter1 refers to the SECOND sheet and counter2 to the first sheet? The naming suggests a possible logic error. Also, why is the second range from 36 to 62 and not, like the first range, from 39 to 62?